# JavaScript, Plotly: How to customise axis labels on bar plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

I am plotting a bar chart with date values on the x-axis. Simply setting the values for bins and bar heights gives the desired plot, but the axis labels (date values) are positioned below centres of the bars (see the screenshot).

However each bar represents date range and ***I would like the labels to be located below the edges of the bars. How do I do that***?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your plot to a scatter line plot and fill it to the x-axis. The labels appearing on the x-axis can be specified via `layout: xaxis: tickvals`.

If you want equally size bars, set `layout: xaxis: type` to `category`.

```js
var data = {
  x: ['2013-11-02', '2013-11-04', '2013-11-05', '2013-11-07', '2013-11-09', '2013-11-11', '2013-11-13'],
  y: [1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 6],
};
var trace = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'lines',
  fill: 'tozeroy'
};

for (var i = 0; i < data.x.length - 1; i += 1) {
  trace.x.push(data.x[i]);
  trace.y.push(0);
  trace.x.push(data.x[i]);
  trace.y.push(data.y[i]);
  trace.x.push(data.x[i + 1]);
  trace.y.push(data.y[i]);
}
trace.x.push(data.x[data.x.length - 1]);
trace.y.push(0);

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
    tickvals: data.x,
    tickangle: -45
  }
}
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace], layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```